# File permissions on PM2 & Grunt & SailsJS

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js, grunt-contrib-watch, pm2

I'm trying to launch a SailsJS server via PM2 and watch for changes i'm using:

```
pm2 start app.js --watch -x -- --verbose
```

Note no SUDO before so it should launch as the right user, I'm getting all kinds of odd Grunt errors though all with error code EACCES.

I've even tried running it with -u root which gets rid of of the errors but I still get EACCES error after a source update.

I'm guessing maybe the grunt tasks are getting run with a different user somehow?

Comment: How're your grunt tasks running? I mean is it linked to the `app.js`?

Comment: Actually it turns out I needed to exclude a couple of directories from the PM2 watch, i'm just double double checking I have it right and i'll post a solution, thanks for trying though]